# How to increase the height of the navigation bar and change the vertical position of the title using xcode 5 (iOS7)?

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7, xcode5

I developed a simple app for iOS6 and now I'm to updating its appearence for iOS7. One of the first changes I would like to do concerns the navigation bar.

I'm using the standard navigation bar UI component that comes with xcode. While in iOS6 the navigation bar was clearly placed under the status bar (i.e. battery, carrier and hour), in iOS7 the navigation bar blends with the status bar.

My question is: how can I increase the height of the navigation bar and place the title vertically a little lower than the default position?
Currently I have this:
[image]

And the title is too close to the time. I would like to achieve this (standard Photos app that comes with iOS7):
[image]
here the title of the bar is lower and the bar is larger (or is just shifted down).
It have been trying to modify the height of the navigation bar through the size inspector but with no success.

It's probaly a very easy issue to solve, however I'm still new to xcode development and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick the view controller in a Navigation Controller, that should immediately solve the problem